# Importing Java Classes Versus the Direct Path

Tags: java, eclipse, class, import

In Java with Eclipse, you can import classes and reference things in correlation to what you import. However, what would be the difference between *actually importing a class* at the top of the `.java` file and *using the direct path* to a class you want to use.

As an example, in this snippet, I import `java.util.HashMap` to use the `HashMap` variable.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    private static HashMap<String, String> foo = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo.put("foo", "bar");
        System.out.println(foo.get("foo"));
    }
}
```

In contrast with this example, I use the direct `java.util.HashMap` inside the class when declaring my `HashMap` variable.

```
public class Main {
    private static java.util.HashMap<String, String> foo = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo.put("foo", "bar");
        System.out.println(foo.get("foo"));
    }
}
```

What does Java do when I *import* a class (first example) compared to when I use *the direct path* (second example). In addition, is one way *objectively* better than the other in the sense of optimization and memory?

I am using `Java 8` with `Eclipse`.

Comment: They compile into the same bytecode.  So the question is - which do you find more readable?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *fully-qualified class name*, and imports only matter at compile-time; everything is resolved into fully-qualified references in the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

> What does Java do when I import a class (first example) compared to
>   when I use the direct path (second example).

Both are compiled in to same bytecode (to fully qualified name, i.e. direct path) while compiling the code.

> is one way objectively better than the other in the sense of optimization and memory?

No, since both are compiled in to same bytecode, there is no performance deference.

**UPDATE** : As @Carlos Heuberger stated in comment, It can be a matter of preference. And sometimes you need to type full qualified class name to avoid class name conflicts.

Comment: last sentence can be a matter of preference... and sometimes of need e.g. `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thanks, answer updated.